# Exceedance probability for a random Gaussian field

Tags: probability

Do there exist good estimates to the probability of a Gaussian random field to exceed a given threshold on a ball, or box? I'm referring to the "basic" field $f(x)$, with zero expectation at each point, and Cov($f(x),f(y)$) = $\exp(-\lambda||x-y||^2)$.

Alternatively, are such bounds known for other random fields?

Thanks, Danny.

Comment: Welcome to the MSE community. Have you tried something?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in the book [Random Fields and Geometry](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-0-387-48116-6), they cover concentration estimates for Gaussian fields over general compact metric spaces $T$ eg. Borell–TIS Inequality

$$P[\sup f_{u}>E(\sup f_{u})+u]\leq e^{-u^{2}/\sigma_{T}^{2}},$$

for $\sigma^{2}_{T}:=\sup_{u\in T} E[f_{u}^{2}]$.

See also their sections on *Excursion Probabilities*.
In terms of tight bounds, you can take a look at the  book by Ledoux and Talagrand [Probability in Banach Spaces](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-642-20212-4).

Comment: Dear Thomas, thank you very much. I'm aware of the book (and will definitely look at it more carefully!). Is this bound tight? Also, is it possible to compute $\sigma_T$ (at least, for a ball in $R^n$)? Best wishes, Danny.

Comment: @Danny In terms of tight bounds, you can take a look at the  book by Ledoux and Talagrand Probability in Banach Spaces
 https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-642-20212-4

Comment: @Danny yes, it can be computed if you know the second moment explicitly, then you just evaluate it over the supremum.

Comment: Dear Thomas, many thanks again, I will have a look!  Sorry to bother, but if you can suggest a source for the second moment in our case (ball and "basic" Gaussian random field), we'll be very grateful.  --Danny.

Comment: @Danny You can try opening a new MSE question giving the details of what you want computed exactly and someone can try to compute it. Specify what you mean by ball i.e. which dimension, metric etc. Make sure to also include your attempts in doing it yourself.